# Is it possible to avoid warning when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to import duplicates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, labview, database-connectivity

I have a table `errors` with the following columns : `id_error`, `product_id`, `error_code` which is already filled up with some errors. I am using `id_error` as a primary key and I added a UNIQUE index composed of columns `product_id` and `error_code` in order to ensure that there can't be two errors with the same `error_code` for the same `product_id`. For example :

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| error_id | product_id | error_code |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |          4 |       1118 |
|        2 |          4 |       1119 |
|        3 |          4 |       1120 |
|        4 |          5 |       1121 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

I want to import from a .csv file a list of errors, some of them possibly already be in the `errors` table. For example :

```
product_id, error_code
4,1120
4,1121
5,1121
5,1122
```

To do so, I am using the LOAD DATA statement and this works properly. For example :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Public/Documents/updated_errors.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE errors
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@col1,@col2) set product_id=@col1,error_code=@col2;
```

As a result, the `errors` table now looks like this, and this is the expected result :

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| error_id | product_id | error_code |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |          4 |       1118 |
|        2 |          4 |       1119 |
|        3 |          4 |       1120 |
|        4 |          5 |       1121 |
|        5 |          4 |       1121 |
|        6 |          5 |       1122 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

However, by doing so, I get a warning for each line that is already in the `errors` table to notify me that the UNIQUE key plays its role :

```
2 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s):
1062 Duplicate entry '4-1120' for key 'errors.UNIQUE'
1062 Duplicate entry '5-1121' for key 'errors.UNIQUE'
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 2  Warnings: 2
```

I want to automatise this process using Labview because it fits my workflow for this particular task. However it seems that the library I am using in Labview to access my database does not support warnings : it triggers an error saying that my query is wrong. I have double checked the query by running it directly in Workbench and there is no error, just the aforementionned warnings.

I also double checked everything on the Labview side and everything seems to work fine with other request. It just seems that this library consider warnings as errors.

I have tried to change the level of error verbosity with the following request (intending to change it back after the query), unfortunately as I am using a cloud DB, I do not think I can have a SUPER privilege nor a SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege.

```
SET GLOBAL log_error_verbosiy = 1
Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

I tried different combinations of primary keys and unique keys to avoid triggering warnings while keeping the security that prevents me from adding an already existing error but I have not been successful.

I am looking for a way to do one of the following :

- Avoid warnings in case of duplicates with the LOAD DATA statement
- Import a .csv file into the table with another statement that would not trigger any warning. I am thinking maybe a line-per-line import with a check for each line if the error is already in the table ?
- Any other solution to achieve what I want to do ?

*edit : I am using the Database Connectivity Toolkit for Big Data by Ovak Technologies in Labview*

Comment: What is the LabVIEW library that you're using?

Comment: I am using the Database Connectivity Toolkit for Big Data by Ovak Technologies.

After a bit of thinking yesterday, I think a possible reason could be a bad interpretation of the '\n' characters in LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' in the query. I will test this tomorrow but I don't see exactly how I can make things better. The problem is that the Query block of this library is protected and I can't really see how the input string is processed so it is hard to debug.

Comment: If that's a commercial library you've paid for, the obvious suggestion is to ask Ovak for technical support - otherwise how about your second suggestion (*Import a .csv file into the table…*) but write the import routine in LabVIEW, checking whether each line is already in the database and only writing it there if it wasn't? That shouldn't be too hard.